# Java- Como se puede repetir una pregunta si se activa el error del catch?

Tags: java, while, try-catch

debo realizar un ejercicio en el que debo preguntar por varios números y almacenarlos en un `array` en caso de introducir una letra se activaría el `catch` y debo repetir la pregunta y seguir con el `array` o en su defecto empezarlo de nuevo, ya que debe de contabilizar cuantas veces se introducen letras.

**Este es el código:**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        pedirNumeros();
    }
    public static void pedirNumeros(){
        Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);

        double [] num = new double [3];
        int i = 0,error=0;
        double numMax = 0;
        boolean esLetra = false;

        try {

            for(i = 0;i<num.length;i++) {
                do {
                System.out.println("Introduce un numero: ");
                num[i] = lector.nextDouble();
                if (num[i]>numMax){
                    numMax = num[i];
                } 
            }while(!esLetra && num[i] == num.length);
            }

        }
        catch(InputMismatchException e2) {
            error++;
            System.out.println("No puede introducir letras");

        }

        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error General");
        }


        System.out.println("Ha intentado introducir letras "+error+" Veces");
        System.out.println("El numero mayor es: "+numMax);
    }
}
```

He probado a realizar un `do-while` de diferentes formas en el `try-catch` fuera del `try-catch` sin mucho éxito con lo que deseo realizar alguna idea?

Comment: Pone el try-catch dentro del bucle.

Comment: mm lo he intentado pero al introducir una letra no se me repite la pregunta si lo coloco asi sería ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException porque dice que supero el tamaño de 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tendrias que meter el try-catch dentro del loop.
Algo así. Fijate las condiciones que estas usando en el while. Por ahí tenés tema ahí.

```
for (i = 0; i<num.length; i++) {
  boolean ok = false;
  do {
    System.out.println("Introduce un numero: ");
    try {
      num[i] = lector.nextDouble();
      if (num[i]>numMax){
         numMax = num[i];
      } 
      ok = true;
    } catch(InputMismatchException e2) {
        error++;
        System.out.println("No puede introducir letras");
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error General");
    }
  } while(!ok);
}
```

Comment: Se ha realizado un bucle infinito, la unica solucion que yo encontraba era realizar esa comparacion en el while pero veo que no funciona, si la utilizo no se repite el bucle

Comment: Vale he encontrado la solucion en el catch e2 colocar un lector.nextLine(); para limpiar la memoria y que no me salte la pregunta y el while dejarlo como lo tenia yo.